# How to move a tile (sprite) with drag and drop in Unity 2D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to move a tile with drag and drop in Unity 2D. The tile is a sprite. The scene is an 'Unblock me' or 'Blocked in' like gameplay.

Because the tiles in real life correspond to physical objects it seemed be to a good idea to model them with colliders and rigidbody. The border of the table surrunded with invisible colliders. I hoped these will constrain the moves of the tiles realistic, when the player moves them.

Then I implemented a simple (mouse based) drag and drop behavior which is worked perfectly except the moved tile penetrates to other tiles and the border, and sometimes jumps over them. Then I learned if I am overriding physics by explicitly setting transforms position (which I do exactly in my drag and drop implementation), this will happen. OK I accept, I should set only forces, ect. on rigidbody never directly the position.

Now the question:

I am stuck here. I still want to drag and drop like user experience, and some realistic visual result. When in the real life a player moves a tile, it seems it is "glued" to its finger. How can I achieve this (ot at least similar) with just applying forces? Any suggestions or point similar existing sample/blog code?

(I know as a backup plan I can omit all the physics and constrain the tile positions by code, and create some tweens to move the tiles. Is the real solution (what I am asking for) so complicated I should vote on this backup plan?)

**Edit**
According to comments I've [added a video](http://screencast.com/t/xHLzlchn8kC):

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the way you are manipulating your dragging. The beauty of developing is being able to do things in your own way. If it works for your game, then don't fret.

Now, i recommend:

1. Create a new physic material. Assets > Create > Physic Material
2. Set your new physic material inspector settings both to 0
3. Attach the physic material to all your wall object colliders. This should allow for your object being dragged to move smoothly against the walls without chopping.
4. Do a check to see if your mouse is over another collider. If so, then stop the movement in that direction.
5. Since your movements seem to always be on a single axis, on collision, tell your object to snap to the edge of the wall object. You know the Wall position and scales, also you have the position and scales of the object being dragged. with that you can write a function that will offset it to the correct position when the collision occurs.

Let me know if any of that works out :P

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it (created Physics2D Material, set bounciness and friction both 0, however using transform.position = ... in my drag and drop but unfortunately the dragged tile is penetrating to others like into butter...

Comment: Yes, the OnCollisionEnter is executing

Comment: Are you using that to set a flag stating that you shouldnt move that way anymore? You could possibly use oncollisionstay to trigger the flag.

Comment: Yes, I've implemented the flag, lets call it dragdisabled. Still the tiles penetrating to each other depending on the drag speed, see video: http://screencast.com/t/xHLzlchn8kC

Comment: Check my answer edit. I've actually had this same issue in the past. You may need to interpolate to make sure it doesn't cause choppiness